# Error initializing ShortCode Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem initializing the Rails Gem shortcode.

I have this code in initializers / shortcode.rb

```
Shortcode.setup do |config|

  config.template_parser = :haml 

  config.template_path = "support/templates/chart"

  config.block_tags = [:chart]

end
```

When I start the server rails (rails s) gives the following error.

```
/home/usuario/proyectos/rails/crowdfunding/config/initializers/shortcode.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Shortcode (NameError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
```

Note: I already did `install bundle` and `bundle update sass-rails`

Answer (score 0):

Shortcode is not a Rails gem but the ruby gem [thus Rails come without this gem as its dependency]. Add `gem 'shortcode'` in your Gemfile, bundle the project and restart the application.